# Insert X number of rows based on variable text string search col C

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with data in cols a-z.  This script works fine for Col data but I want it to search col C. How can I search col c for the string? I get no string found or no rows inserted.

```
Option Explicit     
Sub Insert_Rows()     
Dim i As Long, lRows As Long, lastrow As Long, lngCount As Long
Dim strTxt As String     
Application.ScreenUpdating = False     
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

lRows = Application.InputBox("How many rows do you want to insert?", Type:=1)

If lRows < 1 Then
    MsgBox " You must enter a number greater than zero"
    Exit Sub
End If

strTxt = Application.InputBox("Enter the text string to search on. Rows will be inserted below each cell containing this string.")

If Len(strTxt) < 1 Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a text string consisting of at least one character"
    Exit Sub
End If

With ActiveSheet

    lngCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A1:A" & lastrow), strTxt)

    If lngCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The text string you entered is not listed - cancelling", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = strTxt Then
            .Range("A" & i + 1 & ":A" & i + lRows).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i

End With     
Application.ScreenUpdating = True          
End Sub
```

Comment: Change the references to column A to C?

Comment: Ive tried that.  everywhere Ive seen an 'A' but its not working.  can you be more specific as to which actual change?

Comment: In addition to all the `A` to `C`, you also need to change `.Cells(i, 1)` to `.Cells(i, 3)`

Comment: I totall didnt see the i,3  thanks so much Scott.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate issue has been answered in the question's comments. I'd be inclined to take those changes one step further, and replace the hard-coded column "A" or "C" with a variable. Then the function can be used for any column.

For example, here's your code, modified to get the column from another user prompt:

```
Sub Insert_Rows()
Dim i As Long, lRows As Long, lastrow As Long, lngCount As Long
Dim col As String, strTxt As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

col = Application.InputBox("Which column should be inserted into?", Type:=2)
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

lRows = Application.InputBox("How many rows do you want to insert?", Type:=1)
If lRows < 1 Then
    MsgBox " You must enter a number greater than zero"
    Exit Sub
End If

strTxt = Application.InputBox("Enter the text string to search on. Rows will be inserted below each cell containing this string.")
If Len(strTxt) < 1 Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a text string consisting of at least one character"
    Exit Sub
End If

With ActiveSheet
    lngCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(col & "1:" & col & lastrow), strTxt)

    If lngCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The text string you entered is not listed - cancelling", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, col).Value = strTxt Then
            .Range(col & i + 1 & ":" & col & i + lRows).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```